# NumberFormatExeption when using BufferedReader working with doubles

Tags: java, parsing, double, numberformatexception

I have i a problem when trying to convert a String from my String array into a double.

```
public class ImportFruitAndVegatables {
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Product> fillListWithProducts(){
        String filePath = "src/Resources/FruitAndVegetablesList.csv";
        String splitCsvBy = ",";

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = "";
            line = bufferedReader.readLine(); //Reads the first line, without doing anything with it.
            System.out.println("try");
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                String [] splitArray = line.split(splitCsvBy);
                System.out.println("while");
                System.out.println(splitArray[0]);
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1]));
                System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]));
                Product product = new Product(splitArray[0],Double.parseDouble(splitArray[1]),Integer.parseInt(splitArray[2]));
                productList.add(product);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The file was not found ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(); //TODO: print why the IOException occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

return productList;
    }
}
```

This is the Exeption i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.5"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at ImportData.ImportFruitAndVegatables.fillListWithProducts(ImportFruitAndVegatables.java:28)
    at Controllers.MainController.runProgram(MainController.java:12)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

My csv looks like this:

Product,Price,Barcode

Apple,2.5,1159

Orange,2.5,1606

Mango,12,1603

Pear,2.5,1148

The thing is that it works totally fine with Integer.parseInt()
I have tried using comma instead of period, which did'nt work either. I hope you can help me out! :)

My product class constructor looks like this:

public Product(String name, double price, int barcode)

[image]

Comment: In your `System.out.println()` statements are parsing in the incorrect sequence. You are parsing `splitArray[1]` (2.5) as Integer and `splitArray[2]` (1159) as double. Do it the other way round.

Comment: @maloomeister oh stupid mistake haha...

However i still get this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
 at ImportData.ImportFruitAndVegatables.fillListWithProducts(ImportFruitAndVegatables.java:28)
 at Controllers.MainController.runProgram(MainController.java:12)
 at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: Is your CSV correct and complete? What did you change? Edit your question, don't post stacktrace / code in the comments.

Comment: @maloomeister i have now upload a picture of the csv file

Comment: What output did you get on the console before you got the exception?

Comment: @maloomeister try
while
Apple
2.5
1159
while
Orange
2.5
1606
while
Mango
12.0
1603
while
Pear
2.5
1148
while

and then the exeption

Comment: So everything is read correctly. Now you simple need to remove the last empty line in your CSV file and everything should work. Since you have another "newline" after your last element (pear), this empty line will also be read, which is causing the exception.

Comment: @maloomeister I did not know it cared about an empty line. Thank you so much man! Merry christmas

Comment: Well, the reader just reads what is there. And for the reader there is a new line, so it will be read. (Because it is not null). No worries. Merry christmas.